# Unity array confusion

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

hello i'm trying to make a dialogue box using an array but i seem to be having a bit of an issue. instead of showing the different strings that's in DialogHolder class, it keeps on showing the DialogueManager instead.

From my understanding, I wanted to make it that the DialogHolder holds that dialogue and i got the idea of making it something like this  -->

[DialogHolder = DialogueManager]

but the only thing that is showing is the DailogueManager with the test strings i placed to see if the dialogue changes

DailogHolder

```
public string dialogue;
private DialogueManager sentence;

public string[] NPC_name;
[TextArea(3, 10)]
public string[] dialogueLines;

void Start()
{
}

public void TriggerDialogue()
{
    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().ShowDialogue(dialogueLines);
    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().ShowName(NPC_name);
}
```

DialogueManager

```
//holds the text GameObject
public Text NPC_nameText;
public Text NPC_DialogueText;

public string[] names;
[TextArea(3, 10)]
public string[] dialogueLines;

public int currentlines;

void Start () {
    //lets the box types the char individual
    StopAllCoroutines();
}

void Update()
{
    StartDialog();
}

public void StartDialog()
{
   if (currentlines >= dialogueLines.Length)
    {
        currentlines = 0;
        EndDialogue();
        return;
    }
    NPC_DialogueText.text = "";

    StartCoroutine(TypeSentence());
}

public void ShowDialogue(string[] dialogueLines)
{
    NPC_DialogueText.text = dialogueLines[currentlines];
}

public void ShowName(string[] NPC_name)
{
    //selected a name
    NPC_nameText.text = NPC_name[0]; 
    //this part works for some reason since it's taken from the DialogHolder class
}

//pressed by a button
public void NextLine()
{
    currentlines++;
    StopAllCoroutines();
}

void EndDialogue()
{
    Debug.Log("End of Conversation");
}

IEnumerator TypeSentence()
{
    //types the characters for each sentence
    foreach (char letter in dialogueLines[currentlines].ToCharArray())
    {
        NPC_DialogueText.text += letter;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

if i remove the [size] of the array in the DailogHolder class, i get an error that says [Array index is out of range] but if i just remove the strings that was saved inside that array, it wouldn't matter anyway since it just keeps on using the array in the DialogueManager class.

Please help, it works if i'm using only a single string and not an array but i need to learn how to print multiple lines

Comment: *`[DialogHolder = DialogueManager]`* Huh? What?

Comment: i suck at words but i basically wanted to put the contents of the array from DialogHolder to DialogueManager. The name part works since the name was taken from the DialogHolder but for some reason the dialogues aren't working. The only dialogues that appear are the test dummies that i wrote in the DialogueManager and not the DialogHolder

Comment: i hope that clears it since i wasn't sure how to word it properly